# Find a pair of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $17369x + 5472y = 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I'm doing discrete math. Been stuck on this problem forever. I need to find a pair of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $$17369x + 5472y = 4.$$ I understand that I need to use the division algorithm. But what after that? If someone can offer a step by step solution, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Use the Euclidean Algorithm, then substitute your way up until you have 4 in terms of 17369 and 5472.

Comment: I ended up with 29 = 2(14) + 1 But how would I manipulate this to get 4 as the remainder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
17369 &  1 &    0\\
5472  & 0 & 1\\
953 &  1 &  -3\\
 -246 &  -6 & 19\\
   -31 & -23&   73\\
    2 & \color{#c00}{178} & \color{#0a0}{-565}\\
  \end{array}$$

where each above line $\,\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ \,$ means that $\ a = 17369\, b + 5472\, c.\ $ Therefore

$$ 2 \,=\,  17369\cdot \color{#c00}{178}+ 5472(\color{#0a0}{-565})\quad $$

Multiplying the above by $\,2\,$ yields the sought integers $\,x,y.$

The linked post described the algorithm in great detail, in a way that is easy to remember.

Here is another example computing $\rm\ gcd(141,19),\,$ with the equations written explicitly

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1)\quad \color{#C00}{141}\!\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, +\ 0&\cdot& 19 \\
(2)\quad\ \color{#C00}{19}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 0&\cdot& 141\, +\ 1&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(1)-7\,(2)}\, \rightarrow\, (3)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, -\ 7&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(2)-2\,(3)}\,\rightarrow\,(4)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3}\ &=&\, {-}2&\cdot& 141\, + 15&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(3)-3\,(4)}\,\rightarrow\,(5)\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 7&\cdot& 141\, -\color{#0A0}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{#0A0}{19} \end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

Comment: My textbook gave the answer as 17369(-10588) + (5472)(33608) = 4     is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Vinzy Yes: your textbook did it the hard way, and I did it the easy way (using smallest remainders).   If $\,(x,y)\,$ is a solution then so to is $\,(x,y) + n (-5472,17369).\,$ Choose $\,n=2\,$ to go from my solution $\,(356,-1130)\,$ to $\,(-10588,33608)\,$ in your textbook.

Answer (score -1):

First step: $17369 = 5472 \times 3 + 953$.  So if you write $y = y_1 - 3 x$, 
the equation becomes $953 x+5472 y_1 = 4$.  Continue with $5472 = 953 \times \ldots + \ldots$ and $x = x_1 - \ldots y_1$.

Comment: I did do that, and eventually ended up with 29 = 2(14) + 1 but the remainder is never equal to 4 when I do this.

Comment: After $2 x_3 + 29 y_4 = 4$ you should get $2 x_4 + y_4 = 4$ with $x_3 = x_4 - 14 y_4$.  It's easy to solve this:
$y_4 = 4 - 2 x_4$ for any $x_4$.  Then $x_3 = x_4 - 14 y_4 = 29 x_4 - 56$ etc.

Answer (score -1):

Division algorithm:
5472 divides into 17369 three times with remainder 953:
17369= 3(5472)+ 953 so 17369- 3(5472)= 953

953 divides into 5472 5 times with remainder 707:
5472= 5(953)+ 707 so 5472- 5(953)= 707

707 divides into 953 once with remainder 246:
953= 1(707)+ 246 so 953- 1(707)= 246

246 divides into 707 twice with remainder 215:
707= 2(246)+ 215 so 707- 2(246)= 215

215 divides into 246 once with remainder 31:
246= 1(215)+ 31 so 246- 1(215)= 31

31 divides into 215 six times with remainder 29:
215= 6(31)+ 29 so 215- 6(31)= 29

29 divides into 31 once with remainder 2:
31= 1(29)+ 2 so 31- 1(29)= 2

2 divides into 29 14 times with remainder 1:
29= 2(14)+ 1 so 29- 2(14)= 1

Now we work our way back up that list-
Replace that "2" by 31- 29:
29- 14(31- 29)= 15(29)- 14(31)= 1

Replace that "29" by 215- 6(31):
15(215- 31)- 14(31)= 15(215)- 29(31)= 1

Replace that "31" by 246- 1(215):
15(215)- 29(246- 215)= 44(215)- 29(246)= 1

Replace that "215" by 707- 2(246):
44(707- 2(246))- 29(246)= 44(707)- 117(246)= 1

Replace that "246" by 953- 1(707):
44(707)- 117(953- 1(707))= 161(707)- 117(953)= 1

Replace that "707" by 5472- 5(953):
161(5472- 5(953))- 117(953)= 161(5472)- 922(953)= 1

Replace that "953" by 17369- 3(5472):
161(5472)- 922(17369- 3(5472)= 2927(5472)- 922(17369)= 1

That's equal to "1" and we want "4" so **MULTIPLY BY 4**!
11708(5472)- 3688(17369)= 4.

The original problem was to find x and y such that 17369x+ 5472y= 4.  Looking at the previous equation, we see we can set x= -3688 and y= 11708.